# Should [netlify-cms] be/become [decap-cms]?

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

Do we need to change the tag [netlify-cms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netlify-cms) to [decap-cms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/decap-cms)?

---

> ### Netlify CMS to Become Decap CMS: What You Need to Know
>
> Netlify CMS has long been a flexible content management system for
> users, but opportunities still exist to further customize and extend
> its capabilities. To ensure continued support, investments, and
> maintenance both the product and the community deserve, we have
> decided to transfer ownership of Netlify CMS to one of our trusted
> agency partners, PM.
>
> This move is part of Netlify's broader strategic shift towards
> becoming a more versatile platform for composable architecture. By
> allowing other composable elements to be integrated more seamlessly,
> Netlify can focus on being the centerpiece platform that provides even
> more customization and flexibility. As part of this change, Netlify
> CMS will be rebranded as Decap CMS and will now be fully maintained
> and developed as an open source project by PM.

Read on/source: https://www.netlify.com/blog/netlify-cms-to-become-decap-cms/

I have newly created [decap-cms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/decap-cms), should the two tags now be made synonyms, with [decap-cms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/decap-cms) being the target?

Comment: Simply rename it or would it make sense to create a synonym? Will it still be referenced by the earlier name, even in newer questions? Does the change of ownership change the product? Is a question regarding  "Netlify CMS" identical to "Decap CMS"?

Comment: Ah... it requires more questions (5+) with this tag... but it is a great solution! Thank you Lino! I will do this in the near future.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that the name hasn't changed yet. There's no need to create a new tag or a synonym. Once the new name takes on and users start to mention it in their questions, we can think of renaming and keeping the old name as a synonym.

Comment: There is a new website and the slack channel has a new name. In combination with the announcement it is safe to say that the name has taken effect.

Comment: @Mr.Hugo But even their GH link still points to https://github.com/netlify/netlify-cms

Comment: That is the only thing that has net yet been renamed. Not sure why though...

Comment: We will see how the adoption of the new tag goes... we will create a synonym once we have enough traction. I will keep this question open. Good?

Answer (score 2):

As user Lino suggests it is possible to create a synonym. This is only possible once the new tag has enough reputation. That will soon be the case. I will create this synonym once it is allowed.